# Is there a way to implement reliable messaging using PHP native webservice functions or NuSOAP?

Tags: php, web-services, messaging, nusoap

i've been asked to implement reliable messaging for our webservices in the company. Most of the webservices have been written in PHP using native webservice functions and NuSOAP. After a couple of hour reading information about it apparently there is no way to do it without using third-party libraries.

My question is: do you know a way to implement reliable messaging using NuSOAP or native webservice functions in PHP?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: define messaging service for us.

Comment: According to Wikipedia: WS-ReliableMessaging describes a protocol that allows SOAP messages to be reliably delivered between distributed applications in the presence of software component, system, or network failures.

Comment: MrTechie was asking what you want the messaging service to do, so could you please elaborate?

Comment: Basically i just need the server and client send an ACK everytime a method is consumed porperly.